# Get all images from my Instagram account with a specific tag, not only the recent ones

Tags: instagram-api

I use this request / end point on my website to **get all images from my Instagram account with a specific tag** (I made sure I'm the only one to use this tag on Instagram) :

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[TAG]/media/recent?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&count=50

Until recently it worked fine. To get all the images, I used the parameter count=50 (more than the number of tagged images with that tag).
But since recently, I only get the 4 most recent  images (less than 4 months old), and not the others, which are more than 5 months old.

Is it because of the choosen endpoint "recent" ("get a list of recently tagged media")? What is the age limit? Is there another endpoint adapted for my request?

Also, is there a better method to make sure it get all the images with a specific tag from my Instagram account, and not from other accounts, in case another one uses the same tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are aware of latest Instagram changes but now SandBox mode only allow access to last 20 items.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Hence your list will contain only items belong to the latest 20.

Comment: I was aware of that, but I get only 4 images, not 20. By "recent", does that mean that there a time limit?

Comment: The pool of media is only latest 20 posts of your account. So I assume only 4 of the latest 20 posts have the hashtag you're querying.

Comment: No, thanks for your answer but as said, there is more than 50 posts with that hashtag. The mystery remains...